# Detecting stream data corruption

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, stream, network-programming

I have a server which is sending/receiving data from multiple clients, each attached to a separate server thread. This data is being sent via DataInputStreams and DataOutputStreams and consists currently entirely of strings. I would like to send int-based signals to indicate that client behavior should change, but that data is also currently sent in stringized format.

From what I understand currently, TCP will automatically resend any dropped packets, but I also want to be able to handle data corruption. If I call, say, DataOutputStream.writeUTF() to send a message from a client to the server, what if any checksum detection is done behind the scenes to make sure the full message was transmitted properly? And how would I detect problems?

Would, say, catching an IOException in the server code for the DataInputStream and manually asking the client to resend the message (which should therefore be ID-stamped somehow) be a proper way of handling this situation?

Comment: TCP uses checksums behind the scenes. I've never seen data corruption due to TCP in nearly 30 years.

Comment: TCP is a *reliable* transport layer protocol so it handles data corruption for you as you are at application layer. You can code assuming that your data is transfered in a reliable manner.